# Show submitter a serial number when they complete a Cognito Form

Tags: cognito-forms

When someone fills out and completes a Cognito Form, how can I show a serial number to the respondent? For example, in the case of trouble ticket.

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

Yes! You can send the user the Entry ID number both on the Thank You page and in the Confirmation email.

To show the Entry ID on the thank you page first go to your "Submission Settings" in the bottom left corner of your screen.

Next we are going to add the Entry ID number to your Confirmation Message by using the drop down list of under "Insert Field" and select "Number" just under the grayed out "Entry" title. This will insert the entry number for that user.

[image]

You can even add text around the Entry Number to help users understand what it is. You can see an example of this below.

[image]

This will cause your thank you page to look like this for your users.

[image]

You even have the option of adding the Entry number to the confirmation email subject or message body. This can be done by first enabling email confirmations. Then just select the value you would like to add in either the Subject text box or the Message text box. In my example I have selected to add the entry number to the email subject.

[image]

Comment: **GREAT!!!!!** thx